# Broadcast receiver is not working when application is killed

Tags: android

I have some logic that I need to execute when the user is getting any SMS. My Broadcast receiver is working fine when the app is running but if I am killing my then it is not working as expected.

Can someone help me with this? I have tried all the possible approaches which are present on the Internet but still nothing is working.

Thank you so much in advance.

My broadcast receiver class:

```
public class EveryDay_SMSListener extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private SharedPreferences preferences;
    String msgBody ="";
    String msg_from;
    EveryDay_DataBase mydb;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Intent background = new Intent(context, EveryDay_Service.class);
        context.startService(background);
        if(intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")){
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();           
            SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
enter code here
            if (bundle != null){

                try{
                    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                    msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                    for(int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                        msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                        msgBody = msgBody+(msgs[i].getMessageBody()).toString();
                        msg_from = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                    }

                }catch(Exception e){
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: please post code of your receiver and the way you are trying to register

Comment: Why you kill the app in the first place?

Comment: I am registering it in my main Activity like this : startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), EveryDay_Service.class));

Comment: @Bahman: I am testing each scenario and my broadcast is not working when app is not running/ killed

Comment: "I am registering it in my main Activity like this" -- that is not a `BroadcastReceiver`. "I have tried all the possible approaches" -- then you should be able to provide a [mcve] showing what you tried.

Answer (score 1):

In recent versions of Android, system does not launch app when app is dead 
 and broadcast gets emitted (for most of broadcast flags).

An approach for making this work you should use Foreground Services, some links that may help you implement it:

1. https://androidwave.com/foreground-service-android-example/
2. https://medium.com/@ramkumarv3/foreground-service-with-notification-channel-ac6697c8a6d1
3. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services

Take care, some manufacturers even close these services for battery optimizations like Huawei, Samsung,... . So you should add brand specific codes to make user disallow battery optimization and automatic close of services for your app.

Answer (score 0):

You said registering receiver in manifest did not work for you thus the only remaining option is:

1. create a **foreground** service and register SMS receiver in `onCreate` of
   it (do NOT register sms receiver in manifest).
2. create a `jobscheduler` that starts your service every (n) seconds

it is the last solution but if you wont be lucky between app kill and next jobscheduler work you may lost sms so you may want to make (n) small enough.

**Better solution is to have read sms permission and every time your activity starts read all sms from android inbox and see if you lost any sms.**

Comment: <receiver android:name=".SMSListener"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

Comment: any reference link for creating foreground service ...  I have tried to create a service class but facing the same issue as the broadcast receiver. it is not triggering when the app is killed.

Comment: @sonu there are a lot of tutorials for `foregroundService` and `timer` in the internet just google it. if i want to add references i do same things: googleing. but you will find the one that you better understand.

Comment: will timer resolve the issue ..? because I need to run my logic at the time of the user is getting SMS and that will happen only when the broadcast receiver is triggering at the right time.

Comment: @sonu it is the last solution but if you wont be lucky between app kill and next timer shoot you may lost sms so you may want to make (n) small enough.